# How to remove blank between two gridView lines

Tags: android, gridview, spaces, android-linearlayout

I've got inflating vertical linear layout in my gridView.
When I display only the vertical layout element, there's no space between the two images of my layout.

But when I display the grid, there's a spacing between two grid lines and between my two images (verticaly) in each grid box.

How can I remove these spaces ?

### Here is my main layout wich contains my grid :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center">


<GridView android:id="@+id/GridView01" 
    android:verticalSpacing="0px" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:numColumns="3" 
    android:horizontalSpacing="0px" 
    android:stretchMode="none" 
    android:columnWidth="90px"></GridView>

</LinearLayout>
```

---

### Here is my vertical layout of each elements grid :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LayoutP"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical" 
  android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  <ImageView android:id="@+id/ImageView01" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:src="@drawable/greyr"></ImageView>
  <ImageView android:id="@+id/ImageView02" 
  android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:src="@drawable/greyp"></ImageView>

</LinearLayout>
```

---

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Finally, I've found a "hack". It consists in set negative margin for the bottom of the first image, and the same negative margin for the top of the second one.

Comment: And set negative for the verticalSpacing grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I've found a "hack". It consists in setting a negative margin for the bottom of the first image, and the same negative margin for the top of the second one, as well as setting negative for the verticalSpacing grid.